# How do I customise themes in Carbon Design System?

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to create a custom theme by changing the default colors on carbon.

I have imported the carbon components scss files and I set the variable $carbon-theme as recommended but it is not working. I have imported them in my main index.scss file. I would eventually like to change the color variables and create a customized theme.

This is my `index.scss` file

```
@import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/styles.scss';
@import '@carbon/themes/scss/themes';
@include carbon--theme($carbon--theme--g100);

body {
  background-color: $ui-02;
}
```

This is the mixin I am trying to create.

```
@mixin custom-color {
  $focus: green;
}
```

The above does not work. The theme does not change to the expected dark gray background. How do I do this? Also, how would I create the mixin to set other colors?

Answer (score 5):

```
@import '@carbon/themes/scss/themes';
// Use the gray 100 theme
$carbon--theme: $carbon--theme--g100;
@include carbon--theme();

@import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/styles.scss';


body {
  background-color: $ui-02;
}
```

And not put it into `index.scss`, put it into `App.scss` and import it in `App.js`

works for me, hope this work.

Comment: Also worth mentioning that some properties are overridable via SCSS variables. For example setting `$button-border-radius` to a custom value will affect all buttons. You can find them by browsing `node_modules/carbon-components/scss/components`. Make sure to set these variables before importing anything from Carbon

Answer (score 1):

after hours on debugging code here's the right procedure:

```
@import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/vendor/@carbon/themes/scss/themes';
$carbon--theme--custom: map-merge($carbon--theme--white,(
  'interactive-01': #00a183,
));

$carbon--theme: $carbon--theme--custom;
@include carbon--theme();


@import 'carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/styles';
```

for the right keys to override take a look at this file

```
carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/vendor/@carbon/elements/scss/themes/generated/_mixins.scss
```

regards

-V-